# How can we launch a task from a cron job under a custom domain?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, task-queue

A Cron job runs under a domain, `*.appspot.com`(server name), because it doesn't belong to any particular (custom) domain.

But tasks in `TaskQueue` run under its parent servlet's domain, like `www.example.com` or `xyz.abc.com`.

How can the tasks be launched into a particular custom domain from cron jobs?

Comment: can you use the cron job to hit a URL on the custom domain (with parameters if needed) and push new items into the queue that way? The target URL would need to validate the request is legit (header check etc) and push the required job onto the queue. Seems a bit hacky but cross-domain stuff in AppEngine seems to be still evolving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"use the cron job to hit a URL on the custom domain (with parameters if needed) and push new items into the queue"

-- Offbeatmammal

Answer (score 1):

The actual domain name used to launch the cron job or task doesn't matter.  As long as mydomain.com points to myapp.appspot.com, it will be handled by the same GAE handler.  You shouldn't ever need to check the domain name of the request.  So just launch the task from cron job and don't worry about it.

Comment: There are legacy code in Task Handlers that use Http ServerName... it is why we had this problem.

Comment: Sounds like you need to fix your legacy code rather than add one hack on top of another.